# How do i get my button to stop dissapearing after onclick events

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a website that would generate random numbers and then output a string based on the random number generated (1-7). I have created the button but after i click it, it turns into the output and i can only use it again after refreshing the page. This is a HUGE problem for me. I also need a way to add multiple buttons that would each give their own different output. I guess you could say i have two problems

here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>


<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function Cmajor(){
    let getrandomnumber = function (start, range) {

        let getrandom = Math.floor((Math.random() * range) + start);
        while (getrandom > range){

            getrandom = Math.floor ((Math.random() * range) + start);
        }
        return getrandom;
    }
    var work = (getrandomnumber (1, 7));
    if (work == 1) {
        document.write("Cmajor");
    } else if (work == 2) {
        document.write("Dminor");
    } else if (work == 3) {
        document.write("Eminor");
    } else if (work == 4) {
        document.write("Fmajor");
    } else if (work == 5) {
        document.write("Gmajor");
    } else if (work == 6) {
        document.write("Aminor");
    } else {
       document.write("Bdiminished");
    }


    }

</script>
<button onclick="Cmajor()">Click me</button>
<script>
    event.preventDefault();
</script>



    </body> 



</html>
```

I WILL BE SO GRATEFUL IF ANYONE HELPS!!

or even tries

thanks again

Comment: `document.write` override whole page with its contents. go with updating value of `innerHTML` https://jsfiddle.net/cs09g/dtr4xo57/3/

Answer (score 1):

u can use innerHTML  method and u can delete a lot if contidion and with one array u can solve it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<script>
function Cmajor(){
    let getrandomnumber = function (start, range) {

        let getrandom = Math.floor((Math.random() * range) + start);
        while (getrandom > range){

            getrandom = Math.floor ((Math.random() * range) + start);
        }
        return getrandom;
    }
    var array=["Cmajor","Dminor","Eminor","Fmajor","Gmajor","Aminor","Bdiminished"]
    var work = (getrandomnumber (1, 7));
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '</br>'
    +array[work-1];
    }    
</script>
<button onclick="Cmajor()">Click me</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

    </body>
```

Comment: I really like how you simplified the if statements into an array i was curious as how to do that. Do you have any idea how i would organize the display of the output?

Answer (score 0):

try `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "your chord";` instead of `document.write("...");` document.write deletes all the existing HTML and replaces it with the argument of the function.

moreover you can remove 
`<script>
    event.preventDefault();
</script>`

event in this case is undefined and it will throw an error. the event is an argument of your click handler.

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this problem that was hindering my progress, you guys are heros

Answer (score 0):

Appending an element or string to the body with `document.body.append(element)` will add your new element without removing your button.

Answer (score 0):

The button is disappeared because you are using `document.write();` in order to display the output. [HTML DOM `write()` Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp) is used after the document is fully loaded, and it will delete all existing HTML.

Instead of it, you can set the innerHtml of a specific element. So it would be something like this:

`document.getElementById("displayChord").innerHTML="Cmajor";`

while you have to add `<p id="displayChord"></p>` to your HTML Code.

About your second problem, you can add multiple buttons calling the same function `onclick`, but if you use `innerHtml`, they'll replace each others result. So, you have to create different `<p>` elements.

This would be my solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="Cmajor('chord1')">Click me</button>
        <button onclick="Cmajor('chord2')">Click me</button>
        <button onclick="Cmajor('chord3')">Click me</button>

        <p id="chord1"></p>
        <p id="chord2"></p>
        <p id="chord3"></p>

        <script>
            function Cmajor(display_id) {
                let getrandomnumber = function(start, range) {

                    let getrandom = Math.floor((Math.random() * range) + start);
                    while (getrandom > range){

                        getrandom = Math.floor ((Math.random() * range) + start);
                    }
                    return getrandom;

                }

                var work = (getrandomnumber (1, 7));
                if (work == 1) {
                    document.getElementById(display_id).innerHTML=("Cmajor");
                } else if (work == 2) {
                    document.getElementById(display_id).innerHTML=("Dminor");
                } else if (work == 3) {
                    document.getElementById(display_id).innerHTML=("Eminor");
                } else if (work == 4) {
                    document.getElementById(display_id).innerHTML=("Fmajor");
                } else if (work == 5) {
                    document.getElementById(display_id).innerHTML=("Gmajor");
                } else if (work == 6) {
                    document.getElementById(display_id).innerHTML=("Aminor");
                } else {
                    document.getElementById(display_id).innerHTML=("Bdiminished");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

NOTE: If you use an array to declare all chords, and then use the number you randomly generate as the index of the array, it would be much better than using a lot of if-statements.

Comment: This fixed it thank you so much, how would i organize the placement of the output?